# bigquery csv export UTF8 encoding

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using Big query to extract data as csv file through BigQuery Java API.
When the data is extracted, some french characters are not getting exported properly probably because of encoding issue.
I found a class CSVOptions which has a method to set the encoding. But I am unable to set this to a JobConfigurationExtract object.
Any help would be great.

Comment: Are you able to query your French characters in BigQuery and see them properly?

Comment: Which application do you use to view the CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

[CsvOptions](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/index.html) class  is used for [importing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options) data from CSV to BigQuery, for your case this doesn't apply.

I've tried to import [special French characters](http://www.columbia.edu/itc/french/matheis/1102fa01/edit/accents.html) to BigQuery and export them as CSV. I confirm that I haven't faced any improper characters. I assume your issue is related with the application you view the CSV file. You may need to choose the right encoding for that application.

Comment: Please before answering any post,if do you have any question about the question ask it in comments